# Messagebox does not parse special char :

Tags: c#, messagebox

I'm new to C#, and i'm trying to parse a csv file line by line, to search for a string inside each line and do some action.
My problem is that after reading the line, I used Messagebox.Show("Line: " + CurrentLine); just to check if the output is correct, but while the line should show something like C:\Users\test\Desktop\598\Root\test.xls, it just shows up C (the first char).
I used the same code on a console application and the output is fine.
Is there anything wrong with the Messagebox.Show to show the char : ?

Here is my code:

```
var reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(Filename));
string Search = "test";
string CurrentLine = reader.ReadLine();
MessageBox.Show("Line: " + CurrentLine);
```

Thanks

Comment: You have another `:` in your MessageBox message (you have "Line:"). Did that one show up okay? I can't think of a good reason that it wouldn't be able to display that character.

Comment: Are you sure the first line of your file is "C:\Users\test\Desktop\598\Root\test.xls" without any newline characters?
And in general, in C# you should not start variable names with capitals (usually that's the naming convention for methods, not variables).

Comment: Works on my machine ... check for control characters in your first line.  Also, try something like var lines = File.ReadAllLines(Filename);
MessageBox.Show(lines[0]); instead, and see what you get.  Check the count of lines, check lines[1] and see what you have, etc....

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. I found that the problem is my file to parse. I copied the same exact line into a new csv file and now parsed just fine. Is there any way to overcome this issue and read anyway the first visible line of the csv?

Comment: What encodings are used for the old and new CSV files? You don't specify an encoding for the `StreamReader` which defaults to UTF-8.

Comment: I don't know the encoding of the old csv file, as I did not produce it myself.  But I can make some tests.  How can I change the StreamReader encoding to try different encodings?

Comment: See [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html). Use a different constructor for StreamReader to specify an encoding; see the MSDN reference.